# (solved) Holomorphy on open unit disk and continuity to the closure implies absolutely convergence of coefficients?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am having trouble proving that the space of holomorphic functions continuous till the closure in the unit open disk coincides with the power series whose coefficients form an absolute convergence of complex numbers.
It is clear for me that the second space is included in the first one, but when I try to prove the other inclusion y d
fail to see that the coefficients need to form an absolute coomvergent series.
My gut tells me though that this is not true, but this question arised to me while studying the disc algebra (complex Banach algebras context) and it felt like it should.

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: There's no such thing as "holomorphic on the closed disk". A function defined in an open set is holomorphic or not. The "equivalent question" is equivalent to saying the function need not be _analytic_ on the closed disk. Regarding the example: Do you know any absolutely convergent series? Other than geometric series?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It's common to define "holomorphic on $S$" as "holomorphic on some (unspecified) open set containing $S$".

Comment: Sorry, I found a counterexample to that (\sum_0^\infty z^n/n^2) @David C. Ullrich, so I went to the very question that have been annoying me. By the way though there is indeed such a thing: a function is said to be holomorphic on a closed subset of the complex numbers if there is a holomorphic function defined on a larger open set that is holomorphic there and matches the first one in the closed subset.

Comment: You're having trouble proving it because the assertion is false. The map $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \to A(\mathbb{D})$ given by $(a_n) \mapsto \sum a_n z^n$ is clearly linear, injective and continuous (with norm $1$). If it were surjective, it would be a topological isomorphism. Can you think of an interesting family of functions in $A(\mathbb{D})$ of norm $1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Is it? I imagine you're right, but I have never seen such a definition. In the terminology I  know this is the difference between holomorphic and analytic. Who  defines "holomorphic"  that way?

Comment: @Jonh ??? That series is not a counterexample to anything I  said. (The current question was simply not there in the version three hours ago that I was replying to...) Anyway - do  you have a reference for that definition? I've never seen it anywhere. In the system of definitions that I've used for thirty years a function is _analytic_ on $S$ if it's holomorophic in some open set containing $S$. Where can I see the word "holomorphic" defined that way?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich One does not define "holomorphic" that way. As usual, if $U$ is open, a function $f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic if it is complex differentiable on $U$. Sometimes, one is interested in the family functions defined on a set $S$ that isn't open, and that are the restriction of holomorphic functions defined on some neighbourhood of $S$ - where the neighbourhood is allowed to depend on the function. Then it's convenient to call such functions "holomorphic on $S$".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Here, however, we're looking at $A(\mathbb{D}) = C(\overline{\mathbb{D}}) \cap \mathscr{O}(\mathbb{D})$, not at the space of functions holomorphic (or analytic) on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Regarding what we're looking at "here", there was no $A(\Bbb D)$ anywhere in sight in the question three hours ago - that's the question I was answering. No, of course the functions in the disk algebra are not analytic.

Comment: @DanielFischer But regarding that definition, it's almost like you're trying to confuse me, heh. You _said_ ' It's common to define "holomorphic on $S$" as "holomorphic on some (unspecified) open set containing $S$"' and then when I asked who defined it this way you say 'One does not define "holomorphic" that way'...

Comment: @DanielFisher I wasn't meaning that it was a common definition of holomorphic. I guess that it's only a matter of convenience to define it that way, although I remember to see it in a book of Narasimhan (dont recall the tittle now). And I apologize for the misleading question whe I first asked. I am not asking if the disk-algebra (that's why Daniel Fisher spoke about A(D)) y just wonder if it is true that any function on A(D) satisfies that the sum of his coefficients in absolute value is convergent. I read the comment about the homeomorphism between l^1(N) and A(D) but y fail

Comment: @DavidCUllrich bit I fail to see why its continuous (yes for its inverse) and how it proves that its not true what I wonder. Thak u for ur answers

Comment: Not asking if the disk algebra is the same of the set of holomorpic functions on de closed u it disk*

Comment: @Jonh "bit I fail to see why its continuous (yes for its inverse) and how it proves that its not true what I wonder. "  I have absolutely no idea what you're asking about; there are so many different assertions flying around. You fail to see how _what_ is continuous, and how _what_ proves that _what_ is not true?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I wasn't expressing myself clearly. I knew exactly what I meant, so it was clear to me, but … I should have said "For non-open $S$, it's common to define 'holomorphic on $S$ …'."

Comment: @DavidCUllrich ok. I mean that if you have a function holomorphic on D you can write it as a power series $\sum a_nz^n, for |z|<1. I am triying to see if tha fact that that function is on A(D) implies that \sum|a_n|<\infty. Sorry for the typo, Ive been a while triying to figure out how to put an equation here but couldnt.

Comment: @Jonh Well, Daniel sketched a proof that $f\in A(\Bbb D)$ does not imply $\sum|a_n|<\infty$. What he said is more or less what I'd say - you should explain what part you didn't get.

Comment: @Jonh Hmm.  Do you know the Open Mapping Theorem? (There are several results by that name; I'm  talking about the one regarding bounded linear maps on Banach spaces...)

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok. So you have a injective bounded functional $$l^1(N)\to A(D)$$. If it were surjective too then the open mapping theorem gives that it is open, so its inverse is also continuous and it would be a topological isomorphism. So far so good. But still I dont see why it is a contradiction in these two spaces being topologically isomorphic. In A(D) we have the family of complex homomorphisms with norm 1 but... ?

Comment: @Jonh If the inverse were continuous you'd have $\sum|a_n|\le c||f||_{A(\Bbb D)}$ for some $c$. So you just have to find functions that show that's not so. I don't get a contradiction to this inequality from automorphisms; maybe I dropped a factor or maybe Daniel was thinking of finite Blashcke products, haven't tried them. I think the worst failure of that inequality is given by the "Rudin-Shapiro polynomials".

Comment: @DavidCUllrich Thank u for ur answers. That was really helpful :)

Comment: @DanielFischer :)